# Identifying missing observations in groups

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have some difficulties with my code, and I hope some of you could help.

The dataset looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame("group" = c("A", "A", "A","A_1", "A_1", "B","B","B_1"), 
                 "id" = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id2", "id3", "id5","id1","id1"), 
                 "time" = c(1,1,1,3,3,2,2,5),
                 "Val" = c(10,10,10,10,10,12,12,12))
```

"group" indicate the group the individual "id" is in. "A_1" indicate that a subject has left the group.

For instance, one subject "id1" leaves the "group A" that becomes group "A_1", where only "id2" and "id3" are members. Similarly "id5" leaves group B that becomes "B_1" with only id1 as a member.

What I would like to have in the final dataset is an opposite type of groups identification, that should look something like this:

```
final <- data.frame("group" = c("A", "A", "A","A_1", "B","B","B_1"), 
                     "id" = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id1", "id5","id1","id5"), 
                     "time" = c(1,1,1,3,2,2,5),
                     "Val" = c(10,10,10,10,12,12,12),
                     "groupid" = c("A", "A", "A","A", "B","B","B"))
```

Whereby "A_1" and "B_1" only indicate the subjects, "id1" and "id5" respectively, that have left the original group, rather than identifying remaining subjects.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I could systematically do this?

I thank you in advance for your help.

---

Follow up:

My data is a little more complex that in the above example as there are multiple "exits" from treatements, moreover group identifier can be of different character leghts (here for instance AAA and B). The data looks more like the following:

```
df2 <- data.frame("group" = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA","AAA","AAA_1","AAA_1", "AAA_1","AAA_2","AAA_2","B","B","B_1"), 
                  "id" = c("id1", "id2", "id3","id4", "id2", "id3","id4", "id2","id3", "id5","id1","id1"), 
                  "time" = c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,6,6,2,2,5),
                  "Val" = c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,12,12,12))
```

Where at time 3 id1 leaves groups AAA, that becomes groups AAA_1, while at time 6, also id4 leaves group AAA, that becomes group AAA_2. As discussed previously, i would like groups with "_" to identify those id that left the group rather than the one remaining.  Hence the final dataset should look something like this:

```
final2 <- data.frame("group" = c("A", "A", "A","A","A_1","A_2",                     
                              "B","B","B_1"), 
                  "id" = c("id1", "id2", "id3","id4", "id1", "id4", "id5","id1","id5"), 
                  "time" = c(1,1,1,1,3,6,2,2,5),
                  "Val" = c(10,10,10,10,10,10,12,12,12))
```

thanks for helping me with this

Comment: Can you give more details about ```groupid```?

Comment: Sure what kind of details? Basically, members of the group receive a treatement "Val". What I am interested in is to individuate clearly those subjects that stop receiving the treatment, hence those that exit the group. The dataset, however, is built to indicate the subjects that continue to receive the treatment. Hence I want to find a way to "invert" group identification so that "A_1" and "A_2" indicate the subjects that stop receiving treatement

Comment: To note that in a group, multiple individuals can stop receiving treatments at different time. Hence "A_1" and  "A_2" can exist, where "id1","id2"  stop receiving treatment at different times. Ideally, this should be reflected in my new data

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: sorry, probably I am not explaining myself well. It is pretty simple in abstract. I'll try again. Basically, groups with the "_" sign are groups where one individual has left the group. In my example for instance "B_1" is a group where id5 left. What i want to achieve is a classification whereby my observation is id5, "B_1". However, in the current dataset, the observation "B_1" is associated with the individuals that stay in the group i.e. observation is B_1, id1 (that is the individual that remains in the group). I am trying to find a way to systematically re-arrange this classification.

Comment: Thank a lot in advance

Comment: So let's split it to make it simpler: only `A` and `A_1` of `df`. `id1  id2 id3` are in `A`: `id2 id3` only in `A_1` --> in `final`, you mark `id1` as `A_1`, because it's not in `A_1` in `df` but in `A` yes: correct (and inherits `Val` and time from the `A_1`)?

Comment: exactly. that what I want to do! Because my ultimate goal is summing up treatment values across time. To avoid double-counting (summing twice treatment A (and A_1) on id2 and id3) and to account for reducing treatment on id1, I thought the easiest way would be simply subtract the treatment score from id 1 that leaves the group. In my case id1. This it is why I would like to be able to identify A_1 with the subject that left the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you can try with `dplyr` in this way: maybe it's not elegant, but you get the result. The idea behind is to first fetch the ones that are in `group` `...` but not in the relative `..._1` and change their `group`, fetch the others, and `rbind` them together:

```
library(dplyr)
# first you could find the one that are missing in the ..._1 groups
# and change their group to ..._1
    dups <-
           df %>%
           group_by(id, groupid = substr(group,1,1)) %>%
           filter(n() == 1)%>%
           mutate(group = paste0(group,'_1')) %>%
           left_join(df %>%
                     select(group, time, Val) %>%
                     distinct(), by ='group') %>% 
           select(group, id, time = time.y, Val = Val.y) %>%
           ungroup()

dups
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  groupid group id     time   Val
  <chr>   <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A       A_1   id1       3    10
2 B       B_1   id5       5    12

# now you can select the ones that are in both groups:
dups2 <-
        df %>%
        filter(nchar(as.character(group)) == 1) %>%
        mutate(groupid = substr(group,1,1))

   dups2
  group  id time Val groupid
1     A id1    1  10       A
2     A id2    1  10       A
3     A id3    1  10       A
4     B id5    2  12       B
5     B id1    2  12       B
```

Last, `rbind()` them, `arrange()` them and `order()` the columns:

```
rbind(dups, dups2) %>%
 arrange(group) %>%
 select(group, id, time, Val, groupid)

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  group id     time   Val groupid
  <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1 A     id1       1    10 A      
2 A     id2       1    10 A      
3 A     id3       1    10 A      
4 A_1   id1       3    10 A      
5 B     id5       2    12 B      
6 B     id1       2    12 B      
7 B_1   id5       5    12 B
```

Hope it helps!

---

**EDIT**:

You can generalize it with some work, here my attempt, hope it helps:

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df2

# you have to set a couple of fields you need:
df3$group <-ifelse(
  substr(df2$group,(nchar(as.character(df2$group))+1)-1,nchar(as.character(df2$group))) %in% c(0:9),
  paste0(substr(df2$group,1,1),"_",substr(df2$group,(nchar(as.character(df2$group))+1)-1,nchar(as.character(df2$group)))),
  paste0(substr(df2$group,1,1),"_0")
  )

df3$util <- as.numeric(substr(df3$group,3,3))+1

# two empty lists to populate with a nested loop:
changed <- list()
final_changed <- list()
```

Now first we find who changes, then the other: the idea is the same of the previous part:

```
for (j in c("A","B")) {
 df3_ <- df3[substr(df3$group,1,1)==j,] 
 for (i in unique(df3_$util)[1:length(unique(df3_$util))-1]) {
       temp1 <- df3_[df3_$util == i,]
       temp2 <- df3_[df3_$util == i+1,]
       changes <- temp1[!temp1$id %in% temp2$id,]
       changes$group <- paste0(j,'_',i )
       changes <- changes %>% left_join(temp2, by = 'group') %>% 
                  select(group , id = id.x, time = time.y, Val = Val.y)

     changed[[i]] <- changes
     }
  final_changed[[j]] <- changed
  }

change <- do.call(rbind,(do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, final_changed)))) %>% distinct()
change
  group  id time Val
1   A_1 id1    3  10
2   B_1 id5    5  12
3   A_2 id4    6  10
```

Then the remains, and put together:

```
remain <-
  df3 %>% mutate(group = gsub("_0", "", .$group)) %>%
  filter(nchar(as.character(group)) == 1) %>% select(-util)


rbind(change, remain) %>%
  mutate(groupid = substr(group,1,1)) %>% arrange(group) %>%
  select(group, id, time, Val, groupid)

  group  id time Val groupid
1     A id1    1  10       A
2     A id2    1  10       A
3     A id3    1  10       A
4     A id4    1  10       A
5   A_1 id1    3  10       A
6   A_2 id4    6  10       A
7     B id5    2  12       B
8     B id1    2  12       B
9   B_1 id5    5  12       B
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I am having some trouble with running this code in the dataset because there are multiple withdrawals in the groups, (basically there is "A_1", "A_2" etc...) subgroups, could it be that this is creating the problem?

Comment: Yes for sure, in your example there were only two kind of groups, so I assumed it: could you provide a dataset and an explaination with more than two kind of groups?

Comment: @Alessandro sorry for the delay, here an attempt for the more general example, hope it helps: look edits.